# How to change item view container value according to collections in Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, marionette

I have a view such as

```
statisticsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView : ResultView,
    template : StatisticsPanel,
    itemViewContainer : "..."
});
```

This view is creating like this:

```
var statisticsView = new StatisticsView({
    collection : resultList,                
});
```

For each item that in the resultList, a resultView is being created in statistics panel. In statistics panel there are some divs with ids and when i give an id to itemViewContainer , this views are created in this div. It is ok but i want to create some views in a div and some views in another div. I want to control collection's value and according to that value i want to set itemViewContainer. For example in collection there are a,b,c. If "a" will be created as a resultView it should be in `<div id = "a">`. If it is "b" it should be in `<div id = "b">`

Is it possible? Or how can i do that? Or is there an other way to do this? Thank for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the appendHtml method. Something like this should work:

```
statisticsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView : ResultView,
    template : StatisticsPanel,
    itemViewContainer : "...", // Make this a selector to a common parent of your div#a and div#b sub containers
    itemViewContainerA: null, // Cache container #a
    itemViewContainerB: null, // Cache container #b

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index) {
        var container;
        if(itemView.model == a) { // Check if the current model goes to #a
            container = this.itemViewContainerA;
        } else if (itemView.model == b) { // Check if the current model goes to #b
            container = this.itemViewContainerB;
        }
        container.append(itemView.el);
    },

    onRender: function() {
        this.itemViewContainerA = this.$('div#a');
        this.itemViewContainerB = this.$('div#b');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for this answer but it gives me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object div#a has no method 'append'" What should i do?

Comment: ok i edited this line "$(container).append(itemView.$el)" now it works.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to actually fill the cached elements. Updated the answer.